# Value of '$a$' for which Rolle's theorem can be applied in $[0,1]$ is?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f(x)=x^{a} \log(x)$ and $f(0)=0$,then what is the value of '$a$' for which Rolle's theorem can be applied in $[0,1]$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolle's theorem can be applied if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (and differentiable on $(0,1)$, of course). This means
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^a\log x=0 $$
and it is standard this is true exactly when $a>0$.

Answer (score 0):

To apply Rolle's theorem, we have a continuous differentiable function $f$ on $[x,y]$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$.

Since $f(x) = 0$, this requirement is met for any $a$ where the function is continuous and differentiable, since

$f(1) = 1^{a}\log(1) = (1^{a})(0) = 0 = f(0)$